# SyntaxError: Unexpected token : when using Ajax & Facebook JS API in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, json, jquery

OK I'm using PHP and the Facebook JS API to post stories on users' pages with jQuery's $.ajax() function and it's working fine everywhere except in Chrome.

Chrome is returning the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected Token : ".

I have it alerting the XHR response on error and it is as follows:

`{
  "id" : "30800681_37922830145443"
}`

which is valid JSON. It can't be anything I'm doing wrong with the JSON result because it throws the error before any parsing can be done (i.e., it's not making it into the 'success' function).

The code that's behind this is as follows:

```
if ($('#post-facebook').is(":checked")) {
    // Do the FB post

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://graph.facebook.com/<?= $this->session->userdata('fb_id') ?>/feed",
        data: "message=" + $("#upload-caption").val() + "&access_token=<?= $this->session->userdata('fbtoken'); ?>&app_id=<?= $this->config->item('appId') ?>&link=" + post_url,
    success: function(msg) {

            // Save the FB post ID to the DB
            var result = $.parseJSON(msg);
            var result_array = result.id.split("_");

            // Do more stuff here, but it's not even getting into this success function
        },                                         
        error: function(xhr,ajaxOptions,thrownError) {

            // This is what's executing because the thrown error is getting alerted
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

When I add `dataType: "json"` in the Ajax parameters, it still goes through the Error function but the `thrownError` parameter is empty.

I am pulling my hair out...any suggestions? Thanks in advance,

Comment: What's the value of the second argument in your error handler function `ajaxOptions`? From the JQuery doc this is the textStatus and could be one of `"timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror"`.

Comment: It's returning "parsererror"...the response JSON doesn't look malformed though, and there aren't any bad characters I don't think.

Comment: What is the value of `data` that is being sent? Is it valid JSON?

Comment: It's just a query string containing the value of a text field, the website's "App Access Token" given by Facebook, the Facebook App ID #, and a link to that particular site.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery with post is not possible as POST require CORS support, and that is not readily available.
Use `FB.api` instead, which handles all of this for you, in a much better way.